# Android: Can't receive AsyncTask in Fragment and Display it in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm trying to display data from an AsyncTask which I got in a Fragment but I can't receive the date and display it in the RecyclerView. 
If I start my code there's no error it just runs and there's no recyclerview (no item in it)

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<NewsData> news_list;

public HomeRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<NewsData> news_list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.news_list = news_list;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_cardviewhome, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(news_list.get(position).getTitle());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return news_list.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_cView);


    }
}
```

Here is my Fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

// RecyclerView
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private HomeRecyclerAdapter rvAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager rvLayoutManger;
private List<NewsData> news_list;



@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
    news_list  = new ArrayList<>();
    load_data_from_server(0);

    rvLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManger);

    rvAdapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),news_list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);



    return view;
}

private void load_data_from_server(int id) {

    AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://Here is my Url")
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    NewsData data = new NewsData(object.getInt("id"),object.getString("title"),
                            object.getString("description"));

                    news_list.add(data);
                }



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("End of content");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), news_list.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    task.execute(id);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

And here is my Getter/Setter class to swap the data between classes.

```
public class NewsData {

private int id;
private String title, describtion;

public NewsData(int id, String title, String describtion){
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.describtion = describtion;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public void  setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescribtion(){
    return describtion;
}

public void setDescribtion(String describtion) {
    this.describtion = describtion;
}
```

}

I want to thank you that you clicked on this thread and try to help me!

Comment: Did you check if some data is being added in your list in doinbackground method?

Comment: What does your Toast show?

Comment: In this case toast will always show list object, or better to check with Strign.valueOf(news_list.size()) in your toast and see if list has size greater than one.

Comment: So your problem is carrying result of asynctask across activities? Looks like a job for ContractInterface

Comment: @junaidhafeez if i test it with valueOf i get a zero in my Toast :/

Comment: It means, you need to check your response. You are not getting any thing.